# Submit button not posting email

Tags: html, forms

I made a simple form to meet the needs on my website. It was as wanted, however, I am not able to use the "mailto" function to send the information provided by the user to my email.

After pressing the "send" button, no action is taken. can anybody help me?

NOTE: The form is HTML-only, no database usage, it's just an e-mail bridge.

```
<div class ="Formulario">
  <div align="center">
        <form id="form1" name="formulario" method="post" action="mailto:helpcelere@gmail.com">
    <table width="200" height="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
    <td><input name="txt_nome" type="text" form="form1" placeholder="Nome" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input name="txt_titulo" type="text" id="txt_titulo" form="form1" placeholder="Título do problema" titulo="txt_titulo" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input name="txt_email" type="text" id="txt_email" form="form1" placeholder="Seu e-mail" email="txt_email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><textarea cols="50" rows="8" form="form1" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" form="form1" formaction="mailto:helpcelere@gmail.com" formmethod="POST" value="enviar" /></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
<div class ="Formulario">
  <div align="center">
        <form id="form1" name="formulario" method="post" action="mailto:helpcelere@gmail.com">
    <table width="200" height="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
    <td><input name="txt_nome" type="text" form="form1" placeholder="Nome" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input name="txt_titulo" type="text" id="txt_titulo" form="form1" placeholder="Título do problema" titulo="txt_titulo" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input name="txt_email" type="text" id="txt_email" form="form1" placeholder="Seu e-mail" email="txt_email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><textarea cols="50" rows="8" form="form1" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"  value="enviar" /></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should explain what the issue was and what you did to fix it.

Comment: Without success, fill out the form, it appears that the submit button has no action. Because it does not send, and does not correspond with the request.

Comment: All I did was took out the unnecessary info from the submit button, the info needed for mail posting and mailing of the form is already in the <form line, so no need to try and restate them with the submit button.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, however, the problem persists.

Comment: actually, I just realized this won't work, you need the form action to = a php processing page for the sending of the email... have a look at this http://form.guide/email-form/html-email-form.html this is because you need a senders email address to send email

Comment: This would only work, apparently, if all users of the form are using internet explorer and outlook.

Comment: So uselessinfoguru, with the template "mailto: exemple@exemple.com", we can make a way to open the computer's outlook, and it's this function that I'm trying to do. Without the use of PHP.

Comment: Then you'll need to create a 2nd php file that handles the mail, seen the link I posted above.

Comment: It works with internet explorer, only, as far as I know, so no Edge, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, Etc.